Python Pydantic `TypeAdapter` validate with default for missing attribute
Suppose I have:
class Thing(pydantic.BaseModel):
    one: int
    two: str
    three: bool
    
adapter = pydantic.TypeAdapter(dict[str, Thing])

raw_data = {"this": {"one": 1, "two": "zwei"}, "that": {"one": 111, "two": "dos"}}

You can see that the raw_data, which I want to convert (validate) using adapter, contains two items that are missing the attribute three. I want to be able to still validate this, but give it a default value True for the missing attribute three. However, I don't want to do this in the definition of class Thing, because in my use-case this default behaviour is not an intrinsic part of the class Thing. I don't want users of this class to assume there's always a default for the attribute three; I only want to provide a default value this time only, for this particular raw_data only, because I'm expecting this particular raw_data to be missing three for some reason. (In particular, this question looks similar but does not solve my problem.) So, what I want is something like:
things_i_want = adapter.validate_python(raw_data, default={"three": True})

Or:
or_this = adapter.validate_python(raw_data, default=pydantic.Default(three=True))

Is this possible at all in Pydantic?

I don't know that there is a Pydantic way to specify the default value at validation time. However, if you don't want to modify the Thing class you could always subclass it in a private scope?
import pydantic


class Thing(pydantic.BaseModel):
    one: int
    two: str
    three: bool


def validate(data: dict[str, dict]):

    class _Thing(Thing):
        three: bool = True

    adapter = pydantic.TypeAdapter(dict[str, _Thing])
    return adapter.validate_python(data)


raw_data = {"this": {"one": 1, "two": "zwei"}, "that": {"one": 111, "two": "dos"}}
validate(raw_data)


Wow this is actually quite elegant, why didn't I think of this? However, my only snag is that those objects are now _Things strictly speaking, not Things. I wonder if this will give me contravariance woes later down the line, but I haven't thought too much about this.

Oh but I suppose I could have another adapter for dict[str, Thing] and adapt the dict[str, _Thing] to that I suppose. I haven't tried that yet though.

It's definitely not as elegant/performant but if inheritance is a concern then you could amend using this monstrosity! pydantic.TypeAdapter(dict[str, Thing]).validate_python(adapter.dump_python(adapter.validate_python(data)))

Yep that was the plan LOL.
